# What is the highest power of 2 that divides $3^y(2z-1)-1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have the following expression:

$$3^y(2z-1)-1$$

Now suppose that $2^x$ is the highest power of two that divides the above. Assume that x, y and z are all natural numbers. Can I express x, in terms of y and z?

Comment: Firstly, this is not a polynomial. Secondly, what do you mean by "expression"?

Comment: Cf. [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376442/what-is-the-highest-power-of-2-that-divides-3y2z-1-1)

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you expect. If $y=1$, then the above expression is $6z-4$. Asking for the highest power of $2$ in $6z-4$ is basically the same as asking for the highest power in an arbitrary positive integer.

Comment: @Wojowu My apologies, I have never really studied pure maths, so my terminology might be incorrect. Here is a definition of a polynomial that I find: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polynomial . Why is the above not a polynomial? Here is also a definition of expression: https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/expression-definition/

Comment: $y^3$ is a polynomial; $3^y$ is not

Comment: @GHfromMO It is not that arbitrary as it seems. I have actually managed to prove, that if y = 1, x is equal to the following expression: (1/3)*((-2)^(z+1)+3*2^z-1) . Go and test it out. So, I am searching for a more general solution where y can be any number.

Comment: @Wojowu Got it! Will correct my post. Thanks!

Comment: Well, (1/3)*((-2)^(z+1)+3*2^z-1) is much larger than 6z-4, so what you say does not make sense. Note that this site is for research level mathematics (i.e. for professionals).

Comment: You have  posted the same question on math stackexchange. That's poor stackexchange manners.

Comment: @GHfromMO You are right. I gave you the wrong expression by mistake. But suppose that y=1. x=1 for any z that belongs to the sequence 1 + 2(n-1). In other words, if z is in the sequence [1, 3, 5, 7 .... ], x is equal to 1. Similarly: x = 2 if z belongs to the sequence 4+4(n-1). x = 3 if z belongs to the sequence 2+8(n-1). Suppose that we generally express these sequences as follows: a+b(n-1). As you increment x by 1, a itself will have the following sequence [1, 4, 2, 14, 6...] - you can get every next term by adding (+3-2+12-8+48 ....). On the other hand, b=2^x.

Comment: I do not have any formal proof of the above, but I have tested it for the first 100k terms, and it holds true. Because I saw a clear pattern, based on that, I thought that there might be a way to formalize it, and to also find a more general expression for z, given any y.

Comment: If you give $x$ and $y$, then of course one can describe the set of $z$'s. But you asked to determine $x$ from $y$ and $z$, which is a very different task.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry, this is the very first math-related question that I have ever posted anywhere. I did not know that posting it on two different places, constitutes poor stackexchange manners. Will not do the same thing again.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is a simple expression for $x$ as a function of $y,z$. However, it is possible to characterize all cases when $2^k\mid 3^y (2z-1) - 1$ for a given positive integer $k$.

Say, for $k\geq 3$, we have [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $3$ modulo $2^k$ equal $2^{k-2}$. Hence, fixing the value of $y$ modulo $2^{k-2}$, we can solve the linear [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence)
$$3^y (2z-1) - 1\equiv 0\pmod{2^k}$$
with respect to $z$, that is
$$z\equiv \frac{3^y+1}{2} 3^{-y} \pmod{2^{k-1}}.$$
Hence, we are getting $2^{k-2}$ pairs of values $(y\bmod 2^{k-2}, z\bmod 2^{k-1})$ that give divisibility $2^k\mid 3^y (2z-1) - 1$.

For example, $2^4\mid 3^y (2z-1) - 1$ if and only if
$$(y\bmod 4,\ z\bmod 8)\in\{(0, 1),\ (1, 6),\ (2, 5),\ (3, 2)\}.$$